# Loading JqGrid with JQuery

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am trying to figure out how to invoke a jquery grid from client side to refresh itself. So once the page is loaded it will request its own data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To refresh the data from the jqGrid you can use

```
jQuery("#grid_id").trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Before refreshing you can change some parameters of jqGrid with respect of `setGridParam` like

```
jQuery("#grid_id").setGridParam({rowNum:10}).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

The list of parameters which you can change you will find in [the table in the documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options) (see column "Can be changed?").